# Get data in nested json object

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to pull some data out of a returned json object.  While testing this is the json object I get.

I'm trying to access the height but can't seem to get it.

Here is the data from chrome expression watcher

```
testData: Object
  10100832561876234: Array[9]
    0: Object
       height: 2048
       source: "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net"
       width: 1529
       __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    length: 9
    __proto__: Array[0]
10100856101138364: Array[9]
    0: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    length: 9
```

Here is my code to get the height

```
testData = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonData );
for (var property in testData) {
      tester = property[0].height;
      alert(tester);
}
```

Currently I'm getting undefined in my alert

Answer (score 4):

For loops in JavaScript yield keys, not values.

```
tester = testData[property][0].height;
```

Comment: This used to get me all the time. +1 for simplicity

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var testData = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonData );
for (var property in testData) {
    if (testData.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
         var tester = testData[property][0].height; // or testData[property].height if that's what you need
      alert(tester);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did I miss something? Please comment why I got the downvote so I can learn from the mistake I apparently made.